# Is it a bad practice to include fields on DELETE requests that will enforce them, but only in on certain environments?

Tags: api-design, web-api

I've seen similar questions but in this case the code deployed to all stages (local, dev, staging, prod) will be the same.

The idea is to have a special field on one particular request, something like `isTest` that would allow a certain endpoint (consumed by a web client) to perform a DELETE action that otherwise would fail.
The BE server when receiving this field would also check if the environment is a test environment (ie, not production) to allow this to happen.

The idea behind this is to clean up some data from our service which has some validations that would normally prevent it from being deleted. But since they are test environments and that data belongs to automated test accounts we want to override those validations and clean it up.

I'm okay with adding this capability, it's not really clean, but I don't see any real concerns. Any thoughts?

A bit more info about the situation:

We have a **DeleteResource** endpoint that can be called by the web client. In some scenarios, this process can be completed successfully, but in some others not. This is because there are certain validations in place that when this Resource has gone through certain steps of the process, it cannot be deleted anymore (for legal reasons and such).
So, if this is the **delete** request

```
DELETE /resource/id/
{
  ... // some fields
}
```

we want to add a field to this request so that it'll be as follows

```
{
  isTest boolean
  ... // some fields
}
```

so that the BE server knows that if this boolean is true and the server is running in a staging environment, these validations are overridden and the resource is successfully deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I added some more details to the question. As you can see now, the request is there, we want to add a capability to it to override some validations on demand (on certain environments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deletion isn't part of the test, so why not have that run separately, e.g. after all tests have completed?

More generally, is there a reason why you don't have fresh test environments for each run? You're effectively adding another unrelated dependency between each test run: the results of previous tests could affect the results of subsequent tests.

A concern with your proposed solution is you're introducing system behavior that you don't really want. Deletion is invalid, which is why you're left trying to hack deletion behavior in.

Edit:

Given the unrealistic scope of creating fresh test environments, my suggestion is to have a separate process that regularly deletes old data. You'd have to make sure it doesn't delete data that's currently used by tests, but otherwise it should be straightforward.

That's a simpler solution in that your data cleanup is separate from your running system.

Comment: That is a great point. But we cannot have clean test environments for every test we make. Some of the automated integrations/E2E tests that we have (as a Company, goes way beyond me) run on staging environment, so that data is stuck there and never used again. That's the data we want to delete.

Comment: @fedest unfortunately, the testing setup you're describing is common in my experience. stage just becomes another prod env that no one recognizes is a prod env

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I agree on your points. One caveat is that in order to be have that process we need to have a specific endpoint to allow the deletion separate from the normal one, make it be usable only by this tests, change the tests to use. It's more work than the alternative. I'll try to push for it but being realistic I don't know how successfull I'll be.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider to name the field differently, like "overrideValidation", or "enforceDeletion", not just "isTest". The field should tell clearly what it does, not let the caller make assumptions.

Of course, in your production environment, you are going to ignore the field on the server, so it is still a "special" field. But maybe the feature can start to make sense in the future in production as well (as an administrative tool, only available to users with special authorization), who knows?

Moreover, there is nothing inherently wrong in adding some extra testing features to an API, as long as this does not make the API behave completely different in test and production, and as long this does not cause security and safety issues. Of course, one has to be careful with such features for not introducing some bugs which only show up in production. Testability sometimes requires to make some compromises.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to make these request parameters is indeed a bad practice.  Think about it from a security standpoint.  If someone gains access to your endpoint, they can reek havoc in production by leveraging functionality only intended to be used in internal environments.

I would say variations in behavior such as validation enforcement should be controlled by configuration parameters that can be enabled/disabled for the environment making it impossible to bypass that functionality for a particular request.  This way, you ensure production does not do what it's not supposed to do.